# AngularJs min validation not adding error message

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have below date-picker input control in my html code and i want to disable the past date.

```html
<input type="text" 
       name="startDate" 
       class="form-control  input-sm" 
       datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
       min="minStartDate" 
       ng-model="data.SalesStartDate"                           
       required 
       onkeypress="return false" 
       onpaste="return false" />
```

where `minStartDate` is set in controller and has tomorrows date.

This is disabling the past dates and working fine. 
But the issue is, if i select tomorrows date now,save this form and open this form after one week, the `startDate` will become past date and hence my `form.startDate.$invalid` should become true but this is not happening though my `form.$invalid` is becoming true due to this.

Any idea please?

Comment: Is it really about angular2? Where does the datepicker-popup directive come from? Use the right tags.

Comment: @JBNizet: corrected. thanks. do you have any idea on this plz?

Comment: No. And you still haven't specified where datepicker-popup comes from, and which version you're using. It's not part of angularJS. If you ask a question about foo, you'd better tag your question with foo.

Comment: its bootstrap datepicker